# Any way to immediately jump to next statement?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, console, automation, skip

So this might be an odd question, but I have a C# program that runs from the console, and everything works fine for the most part now except one thing.

Within my program, I have a section of code like...

```
loadFile();

foreach(var x in imgSet)
{
  //do whatever
}
```

The problem I have is that I want my entire program to be automated and run using task scheduler, I want no human interaction. And the program calls the `loadFile()` method just fine within the console, but after it writes out the output from that method, the user must press enter to go into that foreach loop. I do not quite know why this is and was wondering if there is a way to by-pass that and make it entirely automated?

Comment: from the code shown it is impossible to discern what causes the observation you made.

Comment: code for loadFile? definitely not in your current code your problem

Comment: Perhaps we could see the code from `loadFile()`?  Are you sure you don't have a `Console.ReadLine()` or something similar inside that method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a console program, `loadFile()` may call `Console.ReadKey()` or `Console.ReadLine()`

If you can change the code for the `loadFile()` method, you might be able to add a parameter or an overload that will skip over any unnecessary input from the user.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. Yes, the loadFile() method was created by my partner who I am working with on this project, and he is currently on vacation. Looking through it, he was using Console.ReadLine() at the end of his code for some reason. I do not know why it was there, but I commented out and the code is working fine without any user interaction. Thank you everyone who contributed! :)

Answer (score 9):

Change the `loadFile();` method to either no longer wait for the user to press enter, or optionally do it, based on a parameter (so you can configure it to either wait, or not).

Program execution will run from line-to-line, as quickly as possible, without delay.  If it's waiting for user interaction, it's because the program explicitly says that should happen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look inside the loadFile method and find the part where it waits for the user's input.

Answer (score 1):

The loadFile method must be doing something that waits for user input. Because that wait is blocking the thread, there's nothing you could put into the code after that method call that would cause it to "jump" past the blocking statement (the execution pointer will never reach that line as long as it's waiting on the user). You'll have to go into loadFile and see if you can refactor it to make the user input optional (perhaps dependent on an argument switch you specify on the command line).

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply provide an argument to your console application such that whenever you request input from the user, if the argument supplied tells you not to, skip the line?

Example:

```
protected bool _skipConsoleInput = false;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     if(args != null && args.Count > 0 && args[0] == "SkipConsoleInputYo")
         _skipConsoleInput = true;

     loadFile();

     GetConsoleInput();

     foreach(var x in imgSet) { }
}

protected string GetConsoleInput()
{
    if(_skipConsoleInput)
       return string.Empty;

    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When you dont supply the argument, you must press enter. If you do, it skips it completely.

Comment: -1 for "it won't compile": 1) `_skipConsoleInput` isn't static, 2) nor is `GetConsoleInput`().  Additionally, 3) `imgSet` is not defined.  Finally, it's bad design.  4) `GetConsoleInput` should ALWAYS get console input - the `if` should be around the call to it.